Blazor NavLink dynamic href
I want the navigation button to toggle between 2 routes - Game / GamesList
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<nav>
    <img src="images/header.svg" alt="Description of SVG" />
    <div class="nav-container">

        <div>
            <NavLink href="@FirstButtonHref">
                @FirstButtonText
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

@code {
    private string FirstButtonHref => IsGamesListPage ? "Game" : "GamesList"; // Determine href based on current page
    private string FirstButtonText => IsGamesListPage ? "To Game" : "To Games List"; // Determine text based on current page
    private bool IsGamesListPage => NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("/GamesList"); // Check if the current URL contains '/GamesList'

} 


for some reason, the text is changing dynamically but the href is not changing

You code works well in my test, just make sure You have pages match exactly "/game" and "/gameslist"
